# How to get exception message on stored procedure in MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, exception

I'm using MySQL 5.5.
To get the exception message on MySQL 5.6 is using `GET DIAGNOSTIC` function. Is there any similar function in MySQL 5.5 ,.?
 The project I'm working is already use MySQL version 5.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using `SHOW ERROR` and `SHOW WARNING`. To see the last error or warning you could use it as:

```
SHOW ERRORS LIMIT 1   -- for SQL-state > 2
SHOW WARNINGS LIMIT 1 -- for SQL-state 1,2
```

In order to prevent listing each and every error, you can handle a class of SQL-errors like so:

> SQLWARNING is shorthand for the class of SQLSTATE values that begin
>   with '01'.
>
> NOT FOUND is shorthand for the class of SQLSTATE values that begin
>   with '02'. This is relevant only within the context of cursors and is
>   used to control what happens when a cursor reaches the end of a data
>   set. If no more rows are available, a No Data condition occurs with
>   SQLSTATE value 02000. To detect this condition, you can set up a
>   handler for it (or for a NOT FOUND condition). An example is shown in
>   Section 12.7.5, “Cursors”. This condition also occurs for SELECT ...
>   INTO var_list statements that retrieve no rows.
>
> SQLEXCEPTION is shorthand for the class of SQLSTATE values that do not
>   begin with '00', '01', or '02'.

So to handle an exception, you need to only do:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE SQLEXCEPTION .....;
```

**Links:**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-handler.html

Comment: I've try it, but the error wasn't show up. It's only show blank row. I put the `SHOW ERRORS` syntax inside the `DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION` is that wrong,.?

Comment: Can I get the message only ,.? :)

Comment: you don't need include `SHOW ERROR` in `DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION`. `SHOW ERROR` can be used independently. Just include it in your procedure.

Comment: I've got it, at first, it's not show up the errors, because there is a `rollback` before `show errors`.<br>Can I get the message only,.?<br>because I need it to store the error to my log.

Comment: how can you get the error code or error message in order to make an insert into for e.g. to your own log error table?